# CSS: constrain tooltip position inside container

Tags: css, position, tooltip, containers

I think a crude drawing would be best. This is what I have.

It's a menu (A B C D are icons). I want a "tooltip" to  appear over the menu icon on mouse over, centered above it. I succeeded in doing that. The problem is that I also want the tooltip to be contained inside the parent container, the xxxxxx rectangle in the "drawings" below.

This is what I want to happen, basically:

Mouse over D :

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x         _______________           x
x        /               \          x
x        | Tooltip for D |          x
x        \______   ______/          x
x    A   B   C  |D|   E    F   G    x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Mouse over G :

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x                   _______________ x
x                  /               \x
x                  | Tooltip for G |x
x                  \__________   __/x
x    A   B   C   D    E    F  |G|   x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

So I just want the tooltip to be centered above the icon only while remaining contained within the parent box. If It's not possible to to perfectly center it, it has to be centered as much that parent container allows it.

I know this can be done in JavaScript, but it doesn't seem like a fun or trivial task to do oneself, so I wanted to ask here first, if there is any tried solution out there, preferably in CSS, with the least amount of JavaScript.

PS: I don't use jQuery, normally, so a non-jQuery solution is much preferred.

Comment: CSS cannot do this automatically. JS/JQ would be required.

Comment: If you had a set width ( could be fluid, too ) on the container, and a set number of items with tooltips, you could position the tooltip accordingly with :first-child and :last-child or some variation of :nth-child(). Maybe have it absolutely positioned over the middle 5 items, on the first item have the tooltip positioned to the left, and on the last, have it positioned to the right. Similar to bottom flavor carousel @ http://seagramsescapes.com/flavors/strawberry-daiquiri/

Comment: That sounds like a great idea! @Evan

Comment: The container is of a fixed size. The tooltip is not of a single, fixed size, but the text is not dynamic, so i could manually set the size and position for each tooltip that needs it - that sounds like the most pragmatic and "clean" (code-wise) solution :) thanks. You can write a proposed solution and I will accept it, if nothing better shows up in the coming couple of days - and I doubt it will.